# Residue thorem and branch cut

Tags: complex-analysis

Well Let me take the simple example

For singular point at the point $z=0$ applying residue thm, $\int_{\vert z \vert =1} {1 \over z} dz$  =$2 \pi i\bullet res(f,0)$ = $2\pi i$

But my question is for $f(z)= {1 \over z}$ where is the $f(z)$'s branch cut like $\{z \vert -\pi \leq arg(z) \lt \pi\}$?

Is it omitted when we considering the singular point? Or Can we draw the closed curve(unit circle) by not crossing with the branch cut? But In my thought, the unit circle itself branch cut would have a intersection in Complex plane. Plus $0 
$ itself not only branch point but also singular point.

Also, What is relation between residue thm and branch cut?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you are confusing with a singularity? $1/z$ has a singularity at $z=0$ so $f$ has a simple pole at $z=0$. On the other hand $g(z)=\sqrt{z}$ would have a branch cut, i.e. you need a branch cut when the function is multi-valued. Read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_function

Comment: @Pixel, As I questioned to Mr Jose,  Generally What the case we need the branch cut?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which branch cut? There is no branch cut here. The function$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}&\longrightarrow&\mathbb C\\&z&\mapsto&\frac1z\end{array}$$is differentiable and if you differentiate it, you get$$\begin{array}{rccc}f'\colon&\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}&\longrightarrow&\mathbb C\\&z&\mapsto&-\frac1{z^2}.\end{array}$$

Comment: Then What case we taking the branch cut in complex analysis?

Comment: When we need to do it. Such as, when taking an antiderivative of your function $f$.